# Power-up spawns 2-3 times after a restart, but enemies spawn normally

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I have two spawning objects that use the same behaviour. They are being called in the same function and in the same situations. The only difference is the variable of time that classifies what's an enemy and what's a power up.

The spawning of enemy objects is working fine: no matter how many times I restart the game, the behaviour is the same. But with the power up spawning object, it spawns the right way sometimes, but in other times it spawns like 2 or 3 times in the same place. This only happens when I restart the game.

How can I fix this bug?

I'm not fluent in english.

File 1:

```
public float enemySpawnSeconds = 2.5f;
public float powerUpSpawnSeconds = 6f;

public void Start()
{
    gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
}

private void Update()
{
    GameSpeed();
}

public void StartSpawnObjects()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnPowerUps());
    StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemies());    
}

public IEnumerator SpawnEnemies()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    while (gameManager.startGame == false && gameManager.gameOver == false)
    {
        Instantiate(enemies[Random.Range(0, 2)], transform.position = new Vector3(9.8f, yPosition[Random.Range(0, 2)]), Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(enemySpawnSeconds);
    }
}

public IEnumerator SpawnPowerUps()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    while (gameManager.startGame == false && gameManager.gameOver == false)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(powerUpSpawnSeconds);
        Instantiate(powerups[Random.Range(0, 3)], transform.position = new Vector3(11.1f, yPosition[Random.Range(0, 2)]), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

File 2:

```
void Update()
{
    spawnPlayer();
    gameTimer();
    restartGame();
}

public void spawnPlayer()
{
    if (startGame == true) //starting the game
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Instantiate(player, player.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            spawned = true;
            startGame = false;
            uiManager.HideTitleScreen();
            spawnManager.StartSpawnObjects();
        }
    }
}

public void gameTimer()
{
    if (startGame == false)
    {
        timer += 0.0165447f; // game time
    }
}

public void restartGame()
{
    if (gameOver == true) // restarting the game
    {
        timer = 0f;
        spawnManager.enemySpawnSeconds = 2.5f;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && uiManager.restart == true)
        {
            gameOver = false;
            uiManager.HideTitleScreen();
            spawnManager.StartSpawnObjects();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the Instantiate and yield are switched on your powerUp spawner compared to your enemy spawner?

Comment: @Zibelas yes, I don't want them to spawn at the same time, so I wait a few seconds so I can spawn the power up. But that's the only difference between them.

Comment: Where do you set startGame to true?

Comment: Another difference seems to be: why are you setting again the enemySoawnSeconds in your restartGame function? Shouldn't the first file hold the value? And if not, how is powerUpSpawnSeconds set again?

Comment: @DMGregory, in the animation panel in unity and in the beginning of the file 2, with the condition that when I press space, the game starts and the startGame become false.

Comment: @Zibelas because the time of the enemySpawnSeconds decays as the game goes by. So when I restart the game, the time resets too. The powerUpSpawnSeconds isn't set again because it's a fixed value.

Comment: It sounds like we'll need to see your animation then to have the full picture of the lifecycle of this variable.

Comment: @DMGregory, the animation panel only have three variables. But the variables is for the character. About the enemies and power ups, they're treated only in the file.